# How do I disable a CSS rule?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following CSS rule

```css
#class {
    margin: 4px 5px 6px 7px;
    color: red;
}
```

What I usualy do is

```
document.getElementById('class').style.margin= '0px';
```

Then after doing that to reset I go the same step

```
document.getElementById('class').style.margin= '4px 5px 6px 7px';
```

How do I **disable** the margin using JavaScript\JQuery **instead of** changing the value to `0` then reset it to `4px 5px 6px 7px`

Comment: I would probably argue that instead of doing this kind of logic, to instead associate a class with the margin change, and toggle the class on/off the element instead.  Edit: also just a note `#class` in your css snippet is incorrect, :)

Comment: @Taplar I thought about the `Toggler`, But i just wanted to be sure if there is a better way to handle this.

Comment: .addClass() and .removeClass()

Comment: My argument for the class **being** the better way is because it decouples your markup and your css a little more.  All your markup/js have to worry about is the class.  If you later want to change your styling, you only have to change the css, rather than changing the css, and then going back and finding any code that was restoring the margin from 0 to what it should have been, cause now it'd need to be restored to the new default.

Comment: Per @Taplar's point, see Scath's answer below, if you toggle the classes on and off you don't have to duplicate the definition of your margin pixel values in both css and javascript, you keep it all in the css and just add and remove the class reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you make a second class and just add/remove it from your elements?

```
.margin {
    margin: 4px 5px 6px 7px;
    color: red;
}
.noMargin {
    margin: 0px
    color: red;
}

document.getElementById("class").classList.add('margin');    
document.getElementById("class").classList.remove('noMargin');

document.getElementById("class").classList.add('noMargin');
document.getElementById("class").classList.remove('margin');
```

Comment: .noMargin should be margin: 0px

Comment: would probably be better for the default to have no margin, then simply add or remove the margin class as necessary

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution here is to use classes, and use jquery or javascript to change the class of the element whenever you want different behavior as on button click in the example I have shown below.

```js
$("#add").click(function() {
  $("#exd").addClass('margin');
  $("#exd").removeClass('no-margin');
});

$("#rem").click(function() {
  $("#exd").removeClass('margin');
  $("#exd").addClass('no-margin');
});
```

```css
.no-margin {
  margin: 0px;
}

.margin {
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="exd">Example Div</div>

<button id="add">Add margin</button>
<button id="rem">Remove margin</button>
```

Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

A slight alteration to Scath's answer

```
.margin {
    margin: 4px 5px 6px 7px;
    color: red;
}
.margin.noMargin {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Then all you have to do is add/remove the noMargin class.  More specific css rules take precedence.

Comment: I understand now. So by keeping all the job on the CSS is better than making the JavaScript edit the CSS, But using JavaScript to just add a class name is way efficent and better.

Comment: You separate the responsibilities.  You let the javascript toggle the class to put it in the "state" it should be in, and then you let CSS be responsible for defining what those states should look like.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good, just wanted to share another way of doing this. You can keep your base CSS style rule:

```css
#class {
    margin: 4px 5px 6px 7px;
    color: red;
}
```

And then add a noMargin class as others have suggested:

```
.noMargin {
    margin: 0; !important
}
```

And then, use toggleClass to switch it on/off:

```
document.getElementById('class').classList.toggleClass('noMargin');
```

The benefit here is that A) only one line of code to on/off the margin, B) only one extra CSS rule, and C) don't have to worry about whether the margin is currently on or off before switching it.